# converting multi lines of a file a file with single strings per line

Tags: shell, unix

Sorry to ask a simple question, i have a text file named *file1* with a lot of lines mostly sentences. I want to separate the lines with space as separator and print those strings as 1 per line into another file called *file2* how can i do this in UNIX?

The contents of *file1* looks as given below:

*file1*

```
build targets target1 , target2, target3 in both windows machines
please rebuild target 4 build target5 as well as target6
target1 abc/saddggav/aafvfaddf/adfbdafdb/text1.msg
target2 dfdfbd/afbdahgtngs/adbadfdsbsdb/snstnhdb/text2.msg
target2
target6
please take all the files from dsvdfdfv/afedfgbadvbath/dsfbdsgfabadbafd/sdfbdgnsdb/dsfbwsgdb
please rebuild "build target4 and build target6 on sun machines
```

I want to exclude all the paths in between but has to take the target in the beginning of the line and print all the words as 1 string per 1 line into another file *file2*.

Could some one please help me with this?

Comment: What you seem to ask can be done with `cat a.txt | tr ' ' \012 > b.txt`

Comment: thanks Marichyasana

Comment: i have tried cat a.txt | tr ' ' \012 > b.txt this command , this is adding 0 in the spaces between strings

Comment: try `"$( printf '\012' )"` instead of \012

Comment: Looks like you changed your input file since my answer, it is now 8 lines whereas earlier it was 1 line.

Comment: Also your command is different, it has `\O12' with an "oh" rather than '\012' with a 'zero' Your command would put an '\' between words.

Answer (score 1):

```
input.txt:
build targets target1 , target2, target3 in both windows machines
please rebuild target 4 build target5 as well as target6
target1 abc/saddggav/aafvfaddf/adfbdafdb/text1.msg
target2 dfdfbd/afbdahgtngs/adbadfdsbsdb/snstnhdb/text2.msg
target2
target6
please take all the files from dsvdfdfv/afedfgbadvbath/dsfbdsgfabadbafd/sdfbdgnsdb/dsfbwsgdb
please rebuild "build target4 and build target6 on sun machines

Code: cat input.txt | tr " " "\n" > output.txt

Output.txt:
build
targets
target1
,
target2,
target3
in
both
windows
machines
please
rebuild
target
4
build
target5
as
well
as
target6
target1
abc/saddggav/aafvfaddf/adfbdafdb/text1.msg
target2
dfdfbd/afbdahgtngs/adbadfdsbsdb/snstnhdb/text2.msg
target2
target6
please
take
all
the
files
from
dsvdfdfv/afedfgbadvbath/dsfbdsgfabadbafd/sdfbdgnsdb/dsfbwsgdb
please
rebuild
"build
target4
and
build
target6
on
sun
machines
```